# Samba only works when firewall is disabled

Tags: fedora, samba, firewalld, samba4

I have a Samba share on my Fedora Linux box. I was able to connect to it just fine when I was on Fedora 30, but after the upgrade to Fedora 31 it stopped working.

> Fedora 31
>
> Samba version: 4.11.2
>
> Firewalld version: 0.7.2-1.fc31

I've tried each of the following methods to open up the firewall for Samba. I know you should only have to do one or the other, but neither method is working.

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=samba --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

and:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=139/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=445/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=137/udp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=138/udp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

These rules are applied to the default "public" zone, but somehow this isn't working. I know it's the firewall because if I stop the firewall I am able to browse and use my Samba share without any issues.

Any ideas as to what is going on with my firewall?

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question but have a look at this link: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba . Also `firewall-cmd --list-all` will give you more details. You can run `tcpdump` on the server side and monitor client requests see what's blocking.

Comment: I would recommend to configure firewall to log blocked packets. In that way, you can see in log what gets blocked. Then you can open blocked traffic.

Answer (score 2):

The default zone would actually by FedoraWorkstation (or server). Check like

```
firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
```

When you specify the commands above, they would apply to that zone. But the active zone is public...

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zone
```

You could either change the active/default zone or apply the changes you did by appending the commands with `--zone=public`, for example

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=samba --zone=public --permanent
```

At least that was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In my Fedora 36 system, when I connect from "Gnome Boxes", it only works with `--zone=nm-shared`.

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved this issue for my self. thanks to @stanislav-hristov.
newer fedora release has different **Zone**. I tried to access Samba on Fedora host from Windows on KVM, so I should be use `libvirt` zone:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=libvirt --permanent --add-service=samba
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent #for run time
```